# Swift - Asynchronous Shows Images after download

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collectionview and am trying to do an asynchronous download where I download a photo inside cellforItemIndexPath.

I am trying to show the image in the collection right after the photo is downloaded.

Right now the photos download and all appear at once.

I tried a few solutions (including one below) but they all download the photos and the show them at once.

Is there anyway to show each photo as it is downloaded?

Photos are downloaded in Flickr.downloadPhoto and stored in Core Data Object called photo.

Another thing I tried was to use a callback on the downloadPhoto but that did not work

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if(photo.downloaded==0) {
        Flickr.downloadPhoto(photo, context: self.managedContext) { (success, status) in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.appDelegate.saveContext()
                cell.photoImageOutlet.image = UIImage(data: photo.image!)
                self.collectionViewOutlet.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating the `collectionView...cellForItemAtIndexPath` logic and the logic of photos downloading, and moving the photos downloading process to the background thread.

Initially, in the `collectionView...cellForItemAtIndexPath`, set all the cell's images to be empty:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCustomCellView
    // Empty image object or whatever placeholder you like
    cell.photoImageOutlet.image = UIImage()
return cell
}
```

In the `viewDidLoad()` launch the images downloading process:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // your code
    // ...
    // start images downloading in background:
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) { () -> Void in
        // for each photo needed to be downloaded
        for photo in photos {
            if photo.downloaded != 0 {
                continue
            }
            Flickr.downloadPhoto(photo, context: self.managedContext) { (success, status) in
                // Set the cell index you want to assign the image to
                let cellIndex = photos.indexOf(photo)
                let cell = self.collectionViewOutlet.visibleCells()[cellIndex] as! YourCustomCellView
                self.appDelegate.saveContext()
                cell.photoImageOutlet.image = UIImage(data: photo.image!)
                // In the main thread call the UI-responsible reloadData()
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.collectionViewOutlet.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the response @Lil_whale; I was able to accomplish the task with your suggestion (background queue and the main queue) I had to move a few more thing into the main queue (thread safety for core data) but the your concept is right.

Answer (score 0):

I have used awesome lightweight library for this

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

**How to use it**

To integrate Kingfisher into your Xcode project using CocoaPods, specify it in your Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 2.4'
```

then in your code

```
import Kingfisher


// Do this in your cellForIndexpath
your_imageview.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://your_image_url.png")!)
```

Library has awesome features like image cache and prefetch images etc